Send IMAP commands using account settings
I would like to create an Outlook plugin that retrieves quota information for an IMAP account.
I need to send the QUOTAROOT command to the IMAP server and parse the result.
In C# this is quite easy using for example this library.
To avoid configuring accounts twice, I would like to connect to IMAP server using the already configured accounts.
I know that I can send emails through Outlook accounts, but I can't find information about directly interacting with IMAP servers.
Is there a way either through a connection established by Outlook (i.e., without directly reading credentials) or by reading credentials and creating the connection myself?
I could mess with the registry like Nirsoft MailPassView does but I'd like to use a more official way.

No IMAP4/SMTP specific information is exposed by the Outlook Object Model. On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi only), the connection information is stored in the corresponding IOlkAccount object - you can see the data in OutlookSpy (I am its author) if you click the IOlkAccountManager button. OOM exposes that MAPI object through Account.IOlkAccount property (usable in C++ or Delphi only). Account passwords are encrypted.
If using Redemption is an option (I am also its author), it exposes IMAP4/SMTP specific account data (including servers and credentials) through the RDOIMAPAccount object
in VBA:
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set Accounts = Session.Accounts
for each Account in Accounts
  if Account.AccountType = 0 Then 'atPOP3
    Debug.Print "POP3/SMTP account " & Account.Name & ": " & Account.POP3_Server & ", " & Account.POP3_UserName
  end if
  if Account.AccountType = 1 Then 'atIMAP
    Debug.Print "IMAP/SMTP account " & Account.Name &  ": " & Account.IMAP_Server & ", " & Account.IMAP_UserName
  end if
next

